# Generalized Ramsey Numbers

Tags: graph-theory

In "Graph Theory with Applications" by Bondy and Murty, the generalized Ramsey Numbers are defined as below.

> Let $G_1,G_2,\dots,G_m$ be simple graphs. The **generalised Ramsey Number** $r(G_1,G_2,\dots,G_m)$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that every $m$-edge colouring $(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_m)$ of $K_n$ contains, for some $i$, a subgraph isomorphic to $G_i$ in colour $i$.

Say we have two simple graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that $r(G_1,G_2)=5$. Then every possible $2$-edge coloring of $K_5$ has $G_1$ as a subgraph on color $1$ **or** $G_2$ as a subgraph in color $2$. Am I understanding this correctly?

If I am, then that would imply that for any $m$ simple graphs $G_1,G_2,\dots,G_m$, the following equality holds:

$$r(G_1,G_2,\dots,G_m)=\min\{r(G_i,G_i,\dots,G_i):i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}\},$$

where there are $m$ of the $G_i$'s, correct?

Comment: Wouldn’t this say that (blue=1, red=2) $r(K_3,K_2)=\min(r(K_3,K_3),r(K_2,K_2))=\min(6,2)=2$? That’s not true, because an all blue $K_2$ has neither a blue triangle nor a red edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your first question, yes, your understanding of the notation is correct.

To your second question, Steve Kass has pointed out in a comment that $$r(K_3,K_2)\gt\min(r(K_3,K_3),r(K_2,K_2)).$$
This example leaves open the possibility that the inequality $$r(G_1,G_2)\ge\min(r(G_1,G_1),r(G_2,G_2))$$ holds in general. This is also false. The question is discussed on pp. 43–44 of the book [*Examples and Counterexamples in Graph Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444002553) by Michael Capobianco and John C. Molluzzo. It was conjectured by [Frank Harary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Harary) that

> if $F_1,F_2$ have no isolates, then $r(F_1,F_2)\ge\min(r(F_1,F_1),r(F_2,F_2))$.

The counterexample to Harary's conjecture (attributed to Galvin) is that
$$r(P_5,K_{1,3})=5$$
while
$$r(P_5,P_5)=r(K_{1,3},K_{1,3})=6.$$

In order to refute Harary's conjecture, we need only show that $r(P_5,K_{1,3})\le5$ while $r(P_5,P_5)\gt5$ and $r(K_{1,3},K_{1,3})\gt5.$ (It's quite easy to see that $r(P_5,K_{1,3})\ge5$ and $r(K_{1,3},K_{1,3})\le6$ but we don't need this.)

To see that $r(P_5,P_5)\gt5,$ note that neither the graph $K_{1,4}$ nor its complement $\overline{K_{1,4}}=K_1+K_4$ contains a $P_5.$

To see that $r(K_{1,3},K_{1,3})\gt5,$ note that the self-complementary graph $C_5=\overline{C_5}$ contains no $K_{1,3}.$

To see that $r(P_5,K_{1,3})\le5,$ consider a graph $G$ of order $5$ whose complement $\overline G$ contains no $K_{1,3};$ we have to show that $G$ contains a $P_5.$ Since the graph $G$ has minimum degree $\delta(G)\ge2,$ it contains a cycle. We consider three cases.

If $G$ contains a $C_5,$ it clearly contains a $P_5.$

If $G$ contains a $C_4$ then, since the fifth vertex is joined to some vertex of the $C_4,$ we ckearly have a $P_5.$

Finally, suppose the longest cycle in $G$ is a $C_3.$ Let $u,v$ be the vertices off the $C_3.$ Then $u$ can't be joined to two vertices of the $C_3$ as that would make a $C_4;$ so $u$ is joined to $v$ and to one vertex of the $C_3,$ making a $P_5.$